# Magento plugin issue with zend studio/eclipse

Tags: magento, eclipse-plugin

I have installed magento plugin at zend studio. but i can't create a new "Magento Module" project. It asks for magento nature, magento code pool and magento code namespace. All these 3 are in dropdown but the drop downs are empty.. How can I resolve this issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Download and Install (place magento files as referenced in installation instructions)

2) Setup Database using phpmyadmin `(goto: http://localhost` , there will be a link on the left to goto phpmyadmin)

3) Edit apache/conf/httpd.conf change line

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
to

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
(just remove the # )
```

4) Edit apache/bin/php.ini and php/php.ini (same changes on both files - note, as of XAMPP 1.7.1, you will only have to change php/php.ini) change lines (the first change is not necessary on xampp):

```
;extension=php_mcrypt.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

first time you need to initialize the Magento Nature to your projects... done via right click on your Project, in the contextmenu choose Magento Plugin -> Add Magento Nature.

after this your are finished and your Magento Module should fill the dropdowns with compatible values of your project ;)